# YT.Player is not working for multiple videos, javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I have some logic for a youtube iframe, and originally was made for a single video, but in my case I want to use it for multiple videos and with the current code is not working.
Also, I don't get any errors. In my code I use a `forEach` for all divs, but in the this example I used some static divs.

**HINT:** for some reason onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() is not triggered inside forEach.

Youtube API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

Original code from [codepen](https://codepen.io/VeronQ/pen/MQRrBb)

```js
        var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
        
        cards.forEach((card, index) => {
            var player
                , play = document.querySelector('.card-play')
                , video = document.querySelector('.card-video');
                
            // Shine effect
            card.onmousemove = function(e) {
                const x = e.pageX - card.offsetLeft;
                const y = e.pageY - card.offsetTop;

                card.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
                card.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
            }


            // Youtube API
            function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('video-'.index, {
                    events: {
                        'onReady': onPlayerReady
                    }
                });
            }


            // Player Ready
            function onPlayerReady(event) {
                play.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    card.classList.add('video-is-open');
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        video.style.display = 'block';
                        player.playVideo();
                    }, 500);
                });
            }

            // Inject YouTube API script
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/player_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
        });
```

```css
 body {
     background: #121212;
}

.video-cards-yb {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.video-card-yb {
    width: 45vw;
}

 .videos-section {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     margin: 3%;
     color: #fff;
}
 .videos-section h3 {
     text-transform: uppercase;
}
 .video-cards-yb {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-around;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
}
 .video-cards-yb .video-card-yb {
     width: 45vw;
}
 .video-cards-yb p {
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 12px;
}
 .video-cards-yb p span {
     color: #f3e28c;
     margin-right: 10px;
}
 .card {
     width: 45vw;
     height: calc(9/16 * 45vw);
     max-width: calc(16/9 * 70vh);
     max-height: 70vh;
     display: flex;
     position: relative;
     border-radius: 6px;
     box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .card-play {
     width: 48px;
     height: 48px;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1;
     margin: auto;
     opacity: 0;
     background: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1613479/play.svg') center center / cover;
     cursor: pointer;
     transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
}
 .card-play:after {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     border-radius: 50%;
     background: #000;
     transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
 .card-video {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
     z-index: 2;
     background: #000;
}
 .card-video iframe {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
 .card:after {
     content: '';
     width: 250%;
     height: 250%;
     position: absolute;
     top: var(--y);
     left: var(--x);
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     opacity: 0;
     background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, rgba(255, 255, 255, .3), transparent);
     transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
}
/* ------------ STATES ------------ */
 .card:hover:after, .card:hover .card-play {
     opacity: 1;
}
 .video-is-open:after {
     display: none;
}
 .video-is-open .card-play {
     opacity: 1;
}
 .video-is-open .card-play:after {
     width: 2vh;
     height: 2vh;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(88.8888888889);
     transition: transform 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-cards-yb">
  <div class="video-card-yb">
            <div class="card mb-2" style="background: url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/sfacevnz6iE/0.jpg') center center / cover;">
                <div class="card-play"></div>
                <div class="card-video"><iframe id="video-0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sfacevnz6iE?enablejsapi=1&amp;html5=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
            </div>
            
             <div class="card mb-2" style="background: url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/HSOtku1j600/0.jpg') center center / cover;">
                <div class="card-play"></div>
                <div class="card-video"><iframe id="video-1" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HSOtku1j600?enablejsapi=1&amp;html5=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
            </div>
            
             <div class="card mb-2" style="background: url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/ygUe7woTJMM/0.jpg') center center / cover;">
                <div class="card-play"></div>
                <div class="card-video"><iframe id="video-2" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ygUe7woTJMM?enablejsapi=1&amp;html5=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
            </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out a solution for multiple videos using Iframe Player API.

I am not sure why is not working on stackoverflow, but I tested on Chrome, Microsoft Edge and Firefox and works.

```js
        // Variables
        var player
            , cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card')
            , play = document.querySelectorAll('.card-play')
            , video = document.querySelectorAll('.card-video');

        // Inject YouTube API script
        var tag = document.createElement('script')
        tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/player_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        // Shine effect
        cards.forEach((card, index) => {
            card.onmousemove = function(e) {
                const x = e.pageX - card.offsetLeft;
                const y = e.pageY - card.offsetTop;

                card.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
                card.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
            }

            play[index].addEventListener('click', function() {
                onYouTubePlayerAPIReady();
            });

            // Youtube API
            function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('video-' + index, {
                    events: {
                        'onReady': onPlayerReady
                    }
                });
            }

            // Player Ready
            function onPlayerReady(event) {
                card.classList.add('video-is-open');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    video[index].style.display = 'block';
                    player.playVideo();
                }, 500);
            }
        });
```

```css
body {
     background: #121212;
}

.video-cards-yb {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.video-card-yb {
    width: 45vw;
}

 .videos-section {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     margin: 3%;
     color: #fff;
}
 .videos-section h3 {
     text-transform: uppercase;
}
 .video-cards-yb {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-around;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
}
 .video-cards-yb .video-card-yb {
     width: 45vw;
}
 .video-cards-yb p {
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 12px;
}
 .video-cards-yb p span {
     color: #f3e28c;
     margin-right: 10px;
}
 .card {
     width: 45vw;
     height: calc(9/16 * 45vw);
     max-width: calc(16/9 * 70vh);
     max-height: 70vh;
     display: flex;
     position: relative;
     border-radius: 6px;
     box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .card-play {
     width: 48px;
     height: 48px;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1;
     margin: auto;
     opacity: 0;
     background: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1613479/play.svg') center center / cover;
     cursor: pointer;
     transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
}
 .card-play:after {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     border-radius: 50%;
     background: #000;
     transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
 .card-video {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
     z-index: 2;
     background: #000;
}
 .card-video iframe {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
 .card:after {
     content: '';
     width: 250%;
     height: 250%;
     position: absolute;
     top: var(--y);
     left: var(--x);
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     opacity: 0;
     background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, rgba(255, 255, 255, .3), transparent);
     transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
}
/* ------------ STATES ------------ */
 .card:hover:after, .card:hover .card-play {
     opacity: 1;
}
 .video-is-open:after {
     display: none;
}
 .video-is-open .card-play {
     opacity: 1;
}
 .video-is-open .card-play:after {
     width: 2vh;
     height: 2vh;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(88.8888888889);
     transition: transform 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-cards-yb">
  <div class="video-card-yb">
            <div class="card mb-2" style="background: url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/sfacevnz6iE/0.jpg') center center / cover;">
                <div class="card-play"></div>
                <div class="card-video"><iframe id="video-0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sfacevnz6iE?enablejsapi=1&amp;html5=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
            </div>
            
             <div class="card mb-2" style="background: url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/HSOtku1j600/0.jpg') center center / cover;">
                <div class="card-play"></div>
                <div class="card-video"><iframe id="video-1" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HSOtku1j600?enablejsapi=1&amp;html5=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
            </div>
            
             <div class="card mb-2" style="background: url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/ygUe7woTJMM/0.jpg') center center / cover;">
                <div class="card-play"></div>
                <div class="card-video"><iframe id="video-2" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ygUe7woTJMM?enablejsapi=1&amp;html5=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
            </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```